# How I can determine that some packages from Google Dart Team deprecated on pub.dartlang.org?

Tags: package, dart, deprecated

I use Google Dart Team package "pathos" but it does not work correctly.

On the http://pub.dartlang.org, on the page of this package I cannot find information that it is not supported.

Here is link to this package: http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pathos

"A comprehensive, cross-platform path manipulation library for Dart".

P.S.

I only can rely on readme file.

So, on the page of web_ui package I can read.

"Web UI 0.4 (deprecated, newer versions in Polymer.dart)".

P.S.

Thanks to Dart Team. Just two weeks needed Dart Team to `mark package pathos as deprecated and no longer supported`.

Here is bug (Jan 24, 2014): 
[Update pathos one more time on pub to mark it as deprecated](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16296)

Here is update: (Feb 05, 2014): 
[pathos](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pathos)

It's very nice when it's done very quickly.

This is a new version of 'pathos', that contains a `README` saying that users should use 'package:path' instead of 'package:pathos'.

Comment: I think you should make a feature request that at least the uploader of a package can mark it as 'abandoned' or 'replaced by'

Comment: FWTW [pathos](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pathos) has been renamed to [path](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path).

Comment: @AlexandreArdhuin please goto on `pathos` page and try to find public information where mentioned about that `pathos` has been renamed to `path`.

Comment: @mezoni yes you can't find this info and I agree that it's worth to file a feature request to make this more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

See https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16296

I'll look into this on Monday.

Comment: Thank you! But this question is more about the quality of work the Google Dart Team developers. "Perfection consists of trifles". Google Dart is far from perfection. As we say in Russia. "Далеко, как до Китая пешком". "Not so close (far) as if you were need to walk on foot to China".